# How to refer the component in array?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7

I am new in Angular 2+. I have an array and I want to refer into  array HTML file or component. 
I need to fully display the markup.

```
 export interface Termosrat {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  nominal: string;
  price: number;
  description: ????; // What is here?
  picPath: string;
  picAlt: string;
}
export var ELEMENT_DATA_TERMOSTATS: Termosrat[] = [
  {
    id: 75,
    name: 'Терморегулятор WÄRMEHAUS TouchScreen',
    nominal: 'Сенсорный',
    price: 247.00,
    description: ????, // And what is here?
    picPath: "../../assets/images/WH_TS_front_s700.jpg", picAlt: "ТЕРМОРЕГУЛЯТОР WÄRMEHAUS TOUCHSCREEN"
  },
```

I need to paste element here (????):

```
 <ng-container matColumnDef="expandedDetail">
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [attr.colspan]="columnsToDisplay.length">
          <div class="element-detail" [@detailExpand]="element == expandedElement ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed'">
            <div class="example-element-diagram">
              <div class="element-name"> <img src={{element.picPath}} alt={{element.picAlt}} height="360" width="360" > </div>
            </div>
            <div class="element-description">
              ???? 
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </ng-container>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you have some `Html`s in your object and you want to bind and display it.

In that case, you need to define your types as `string` like below

```
export interface Termosrat {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  nominal: string;
  price: number;
  description: string;
  picPath: string;
  picAlt: string;
}
export var ELEMENT_DATA_TERMOSTATS: Termosrat[] = [
  {
    id: 75,
    name: 'Терморегулятор WÄRMEHAUS TouchScreen',
    nominal: 'Сенсорный',
    price: 247.00,
    description: '<div><ul><li>Item 1</li><li>Item 2</li></ul></div>', // And what is here?
    picPath: "../../assets/images/WH_TS_front_s700.jpg", picAlt: "ТЕРМОРЕГУЛЯТОР WÄRMEHAUS TOUCHSCREEN"
  },
```

then bind it to innerHtml as below

```
    <div class="element-description" [innerHtml]="element.description">
    </div>
```

**BUT** this is not enough, you need to add a `safeHtmlPipe` to your application and after that change it to

```
    <div class="element-description" [innerHtml]="element.description | safeHtml">
    </div>
```

### Implementing SafeHtml

safe-html.pipe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
  name: 'safeHtml',
})
export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private sanitized: DomSanitizer) { }

  transform(value: any): SafeHtml {
    return this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
  }

}
```

and add it to both `declarations` and `providers` of your `app.module.ts`

Comment: Thanks so much. You answered to my question. Sorry that I can't give like to your answer. This is my first question and I have no anough reputation.

Comment: Sorry. And one more question

Could I do like that?



export var ELEMENT_DATA_TERMOSTATS: Termosrat[] = [
  {
    ...
    description: `<app-touchscreen></app-touchscreen>`
    ...
  },

If yes, how?

Comment: for `bypassSecurityTrustHtml`